# JavaScript equivalent of Python's rsplit

Tags: javascript, python, string, split

> str.rsplit([sep[, maxsplit]])
>
> Return a
> list of the words in the string, using
> sep as the delimiter string. If
> maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
> splits are done, the rightmost ones.
> If sep is not specified or None, any
> whitespace string is a separator.
> Except for splitting from the right,
> rsplit() behaves like split() which is
> described in detail below.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit

Comment: Not built-in. You have to write your own function. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote my own crappy version.  But I was pretty sure somebody on Stacko could write me a better one (and they did).

Comment: please re open the selected answer is wrong as user gardah notified it already. eg "splitme".rsplit("x",1) returns ["","splitme"]   "closely" is not "equivalent"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
String.prototype.rsplit = function(sep, maxsplit) {
    var split = this.split(sep);
    return maxsplit ? [ split.slice(0, -maxsplit).join(sep) ].concat(split.slice(-maxsplit)) : split;
}
```

This one functions more closely to the Python version

"blah,derp,blah,beep".rsplit(",",1) // [ 'blah,derp,blah', 'beep' ]

Comment: Yes, this is good, but I think it should be this.split(sep || /\s+/), like in Hans' version.

Comment: I agree ;-),the Python doc linked to explicitly states : "If sep is not specified or None, any whitespace string is a separator".

Comment: I omitted it based on Array.split's normal behavior. 'blah,derp'.split() or 'blah,derp'.split(undefined) will both yeild [ 'blah,derp' ] Not to say it shouldn't still be included, there might be some edge cases I'd not thought of.

Comment: a.slice(a.indexOf(delimiter)+1)

Comment: Here is a refactoring for a version that does not pollute the global String object: https://github.com/mozilla/OpenWPM/pull/409/files

Comment: @MorganARRAllen Why you do not choose for use a Regular Expression? Will be faster than create a new String object's functionality and then traverse the entire String structure.

Comment: NOTE for this case: 'a b'.rsplit('-', 1) this implementation yields ['', 'a b'] . I would expect the result ['a b'] instead.

Comment: rsplit(undefined, maxsplit=1 )  "a//b//c//d".rsplit("//",4)   "a//b//c//d".rsplit('//', 2147483642)  "aaa".rsplit("aaa",0)     ( all from python testsuite, my -1 (thanks a lot !) answer now pass almost of them )

Comment: "a|b|c|d".rsplit("|",4)  "a|b|c|d".rsplit("|", 0)  don't pass either

Comment: see https://pygame-web.github.io/showroom/pypad_git.html#src/test_rsplit.py  to use  as a main.py + pygbag for easier testing

Answer (score 8):

You can also use JS String functions **split** + **slice**

Python:

`'a,b,c'.rsplit(',' -1)[0]` will give you `'a,b'`

Javascript:

`'a,b,c'.split(',').slice(0, -1).join(',')` will also give you `'a,b'`

Comment: But you could not do something like `const [initial, last] = 'a,b,c'.rsplit(',')`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the semantics of JavaScript split are acceptable use the following

```
String.prototype.rsplit = function (delimiter, limit) {
  delimiter = this.split (delimiter || /s+/);
  return limit ? delimiter.splice (-limit) : delimiter;
}
```

Comment: This does not return the same behavior as rsplit with limit > 1.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is more "equivalent" until a bug is found, "close" is not acceptable for an answer. Especially if you are trying to port python code without knowing javascript.

```js
String.prototype.rsplit = function(sep, maxsplit) {
    var result = []
    var src = this
    var nullsep = false

    if ( (sep === undefined) || (sep === null) || (!sep) ) {
        sep = " "
        nullsep = true
        src = src.replaceAll(sep+sep,sep)
        src = src.replaceAll(sep+sep,sep)
    }

    if (nullsep && !src)
        return []

    if (maxsplit === 0  )
        return [src]

    maxsplit = maxsplit || -1

    var data = src.split(sep)


    if (!maxsplit || (maxsplit<0) || (data.length==maxsplit+1) )
        return data

    while (data.length && (result.length < maxsplit)) {
        result.push( data.pop() )
    }
    if (result.length) {
        result.reverse()
        if (data.length>1) {
            // thx @imkzh
            return [data.join(sep), ...result ]
        }
        return result
    }
    return [this]
}
```

Comment: this would return something like ["/a", Array(1)]: `"a/b/c".rsplit("/", 1)` => `['a/b', ['c']]`

Comment: nice catch, added a fix

Comment: Sorry, by no offence, I highly recommend to test your code before hit submit button, this code still returns nested array. (Try `"1/2/3/4".rsplit("/", 2)` and you get `['1/2', ['3', '4']]`). I tried putting "..."(3 dots) before `result` in original code:line(-6) and seems worked fine.

Comment: i don't know javascript so i hope i got it right this time. Your suggestions and testing are very welcome.

Comment: Just for educating the person who can't read neither js or python and put -1 to this answer, this one is tested against python(wasm) rsplit testsuite directly in the browser !  https://pygame-web.github.io/showroom/pypad_git.html#src/test_rsplit.py

Comment: still failing on `"bbobbbobbA".rsplit(sep='bbobb',maxsplit=-1)`  and  `"abbbc".rsplit(sep='bb',maxsplit=-1)`